# set is being modified and then seems to magically revert

Tags: python, multithreading, set, synchronization

I'm trying to build a channel with reliable delivery on top of an unreliable channel (it's an exercise, the unreliable channel explicitly drops some of its packets). I have an `acks` set that contains `(address, sequence_number)` pairs. When an ack is received over the channel it's added to the `acks` set and a condition variable is notified:

```
msg, addr = self.unreliable_channel.recv()
if isinstance(msg, Ack):
    with self.acks_cond:
        self.acks.add((addr, msg.ack))
        print "{} got an ack: {} ({})".format(self.port, self.acks, hex(id(self.acks)))
        self.acks_cond.notify()
```

A different thread is listening on the condition variable and checking for the acks in the thread:

```
with self.acks_cond:
    max_wait = 2 * self.unreliable_channel.delay_avg
    start = time.time()
    while not ((addr, msg.seq) in self.acks) and (time.time() - start < max_wait):
        print "{}: self.acks is {} ({})".format(self.port, self.acks, hex(id(self.acks)))
        self.acks_cond.wait(0.1)
    print "{} waited for ack of {} from {}: {} ({})".format(self.port, msg.seq, addr, self.acks, hex(id(self.acks)))
    if (addr, msg.seq) in self.acks:
        print '!' * 10000
        # self.acks.remove((addr, msg.seq))
        return
```

However, the second snippet can't seem to see the modified set:

```
10000 got an ack: set([(('192.168.1.7', 10001), 1), 'toplel']) (0x7f40a944ced0)
10000: self.acks is set(['toplel']) (0x7f40a944ced0)
```

(`'toplel'` is a string I threw in the set to make sure it wasn't just somehow being emptied)

Anyone have an idea of what would be messing this up?

Code dump below: (tried making a SSCCE but couldn't seem to reproduce the behavior -- I'll try some more though if I get one).

```
import threading
import time
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple

Message = namedtuple('Message', ['seq', 'data'])
Ack = namedtuple('Ack', ['ack'])

class ReliableChannel:
    '''Building on top of UnreliableChannel, this channel supports
    guarenteed eventual delivery, FIFO delivery on a per-destination
    basis, and no duplicated delivery.'''

    def __init__(self, unreliable_channel):
        self.unreliable_channel = unreliable_channel

        # a set of (addr, seq) pairs for which we've recieved acks
        print "INITIALIZING THE TOPLEL"
        self.acks = set(["toplel"])
        self.acks_cond = threading.Condition()

        self.seq = defaultdict(int)

        self.port = self.unreliable_channel.sock.getsockname()[1]
        print 'self.port: {}'.format(self.port)

        # leftoff: the thread we started can't seem to modify self.acks so that unicast can see it
        self.listener = threading.Thread(target=self.listen)
        self.listener.start()

    def listen(self):
        while True:
            msg, addr = self.unreliable_channel.recv()
            if isinstance(msg, Ack):
                with self.acks_cond:
                    self.acks.add((addr, msg.ack))
                    print "{} got an ack: {} ({})".format(self.port, self.acks, hex(id(self.acks)))
                    self.acks_cond.notify()
            else:
                ack = Ack(msg.seq)
                self.unreliable_channel.unicast(ack, addr)
                print '{} Got message {} and sent {} back to {}'.format(self.port, msg, ack, addr)

    def unicast(self, msg, addr):
        self.seq[addr] += 1  # get the sequence number for this message
        msg = Message(self.seq[addr], msg)
        print '{} Trying to send message {} to {}'.format(self.port, msg, addr)
        while True:
            # send a message
            self.unreliable_channel.unicast(msg, addr)

            # wait for an ack with a timeout
            with self.acks_cond:
                max_wait = 2 * self.unreliable_channel.delay_avg
                start = time.time()
                while not ((addr, msg.seq) in self.acks) and (time.time() - start < max_wait):
                    print "{}: self.acks is {} ({})".format(self.port, self.acks, hex(id(self.acks)))
                    self.acks_cond.wait(0.1)
                print "{} waited for ack of {} from {}: {} ({})".format(self.port, msg.seq, addr, self.acks, hex(id(self.acks)))
                if (addr, msg.seq) in self.acks:
                    print '!' * 10000
                    # self.acks.remove((addr, msg.seq))
                    return
```

**edit**: After doing some more messing around, it seems like the sets sometimes "diverge" in the two threads after a while. Depending on where I do it in `listen`, the modifications to the list sometimes take, but after that, it seems like each thread is working with its own copy of the set (ie, I tried adding stuff to the set in both threads).

Comment: Did you try checking and reporting the id of the set to ensure you're working from the same set object?

Comment: @AaronHall Yup, the code the prints it is above, and its in the two lines of output I've included. There's perhaps the possibility that I'm somehow messing up address spaces and getting the same virtual address representing two different objects, but I feel like that's unlikely.

Comment: I doubt your data is "diverging". But as you can tell from my earlier question, I'm a bit TLDR right now. Sorry! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-answer: Knew it be something fairly stupid. The `__init__` method above launches a thread, and it was being run in the `__init__` method of a `multiprocessing.Process` subclass. Meaning the thread running `listen` was being launched in one process, while the thread running `unicast` was being run in a separate one, with a dup-ed copy of the set I guess.

Should've probably realized this sooner but the fact that the `id`s were the same was throwing me off -- I guess I figured a forked process would get its own virtual addresses, so the odds of it being the same one would be low. Didn't think to assume it would just re-use the same virtual address.

tl;dr: `id(x) == id(y)` doesn't mean `x` and `y` are the same object if you're messing with multiprocessing.