# instance variables in a python class diverging in different threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I've posted about my specific woes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392344/set-is-being-modified-and-then-seems-to-magically-revert), but I'm just wondering generally, if there's any situation in which an instance variables would end up "diverging" in a thread. Ie,

```
class Foo:
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = 0
    self.lock = threading.Lock()

  def bar(self):
    with self.lock:
      self.x += 1

  def baz(self):
    with self.lock:
      self.x += 2
```

If `f = Foo()` and `f.bar` and `f.baz` get called in different threads, is there any possibility that changes by `bar` won't be reflected in `baz`, or vice versa?

Comment: I don't know much about threading in this context, but it looks like you don't have a minimum demonstrable example. Is there potentially a conflict between bar and baz incrementing x?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a `Lock` even though the `f.baz` and `f.bar` is called from two different threads the value of `x` will not be stale.

This is because per `Foo` class instance there can be only one thread can invoke `baz` or `bar` at a given time. When one method is in the processing the other method can not be invoked and there won't be a race condition taking place because both read-modify-write operations in `baz` and `bar` are done exclusively.